# Connect to a device via WiFi SSID to enter configuration in a web page

Tags: wifi

There are many devices - so initially they have their own Wi-Fi name, I can connect via this device's WiFi, enter some configuration on a web page including my home Wi-Fi name and password.

Then this device restarts, connects to home Wi-Fi and uses previously entered values for some feature, like weather city

I wonder, is there any manuals to implement this on Raspberry pi zero?

Comment: Are you talking about saving the configuration for the wifi setting you put?

Comment: I was trying to do something like wifi routers have. If you have a router and it's reset, 1st you connect to a router wifi, like "RouterWIFIGuest", then when you go to router wi-fi you can go to like 192.168.0.1 and set some parameters.


Similar, I should connect to my device WiFi like, "MyDeviceWiFi", then I go to 192.168.0.34, then a web page opens and has some fields and I can set "Home Wifi name", "Home Wifi Password". Then I restart my device and now my device connects to home wifi using those settings

Comment: So you are trying to make one of those webpages on your pi that manages the settings for your hotspot (assuming that you are trying to implement this on a hotspot)? Those webpages are meant for editing the settings of the router/internet it it is on. You are trying to implement that?

Comment: I think so. For instance, I connect to my PI device Wifi "PiDeviceWifi", go to 192.168.n.n., web page appears, I enter: homeWifiName, homeWifiPass, WeatherCity. Then restart device. It restarts, connects to home wifi and shows weather for the city I entered. 

I think this should be a hot spot, yes. But I don't even know where to start to make such thing. Should I create a Hot Spot + install web server etc, would love to have some directions. I know how to show weather, I just need to do this Wifi related part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can install your hotspot. One way is to use hostapd, and set up all through the terminal. The second option is to use Network Manager and set up a hotspot through GUI. [See this tutorial for installing hostapd](https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/)

As for the Network Manager, go to the terminal and do `sudo raspi-config` Select Advanced Option > Network Config > Network Manager.
You will get disconnected from the wifi. Reboot your Raspberry pi.

On your home screen on the Raspberry Pi OS, click on the wifi icon, Advanced Option, and Create Hotspot. Put the info about your hotspot, and finally, create it. You now have a hotspot. You can give it internet by connecting an ethernet cable.